# Does Mathematica solve transfer functions differently from MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, control-systems

I'm using *Mathematica* to derive the transfer functions for a three phase AC/DC inverter.

Given below is the code for the derivation of the transfer function for a third order filter (LCL) connected system:

```
Clear[Asys, Bsys, Csys, Dsys]

numericalvalues = {
R1 -> 0.,
R2 -> 0.,
Rd -> 0.,
Lff ->  2.3*10^-3,
Lgf -> 0.93*10^-3,
Cf -> 10*10^-6,
Vbatt ->  400,
Vdc -> 800,
d -> 1};

Asys = {{(Rd - R1)/Lff, -(Rd/Lff), 1/Lff}, {-(Rd/Lgf), (R2 + Rd)/Lgf, 
1/Lgf}, {1/Cf, -(1/Cf), 0}};

Bsys = {{d/Lff}, {0}, {0}};
Csys = {{0, 1, 0}};

systf4 = TransferFunctionModel[Csys .Inverse[(( {
    {s, 0, 0},
    {0, s, 0},
    {0, 0, s}
   } ) - Asys)].Bsys, s]

Convertertf4 = Simplify[systf4 /. numericalvalues // N]
```

This results in the following transfer function:

```
(4.67508*10^10/(s^3+6.40486*10^7 s))
```

The transfer function calculated by this code differs from the same system solved in MATLAB given below:

```
 4.675*10^10/ (s^3 + 1.527*10^-12 s^2 + 6.405*10^7 s + 9.78*10^-5)
```

Does *Mathematica* have a tolerance limit that it is assuming the small numbers are insignificant and can be ignored? Has anyone had any experience with this before?

Comment: I think you'll need to provide more information so that we can reproduce the problem. If you can find a small order example (for instance, does it happen with a 2 by 2 system?) then it will help.

Comment: sorry should try to be more specific! I've added the code, it's a complicated problem but I imagine its a simple solution.

Comment: I'll ask again: can you reproduce the problem in a more concise setting? Say with a single input single output transfer function? With a 2 by 2 system?

Comment: No I can't seem to replicate the same problem with a simpler system. Matlab and Mathematica give the same answers when I compare a lower order system, but the lower order system is not related to what I'm trying to model here.

Comment: I notice you have a term in i1d/dd that is order 10^25. What is the dynamic range of Matlab's variables? There's a good chance that you have exceeded what Matlab can handle with numbers of this size. So I would try a SISO model with parameters of this size and see if you can find the discrepancy there.

Comment: I'm not sure what the dynamic range of Matlab is but I've added above an edit whereby solving for the transfer funcntions using G(s) = C.((sI-A)^-1).B yields the correct answer. Is it possible there's just a limitation in how TransferFunctionModel can hadle such large numbers?

Comment: I usually work with a system of order 4 and I have the same problem. After I get the s.s $\dot{x}(t)=Ax(t)+Bu(t)$ and I want to get the transfer function, Mathematica doesn't return the correct t.f (matlab does). Also that makes me to get the wrong poles or zeros. However I have never had problems using $h(s)=C(sI-A)^{-1}B$

Answer (score 6):

Might try without approximate values. To do this, instead use

```
numericValues = {Vphrms -> 230, 
   Vlinerms -> Sqrt[3] 230, \[Omega] -> 2 \[Pi] 50, L1 -> 23*10^-4, 
   L2 -> 93*10^-5, Cf -> 10*10^-6, Co -> 600*10^-6, rd -> 3/10, 
   r1 -> 1/5, r2 -> 1/5, Dd -> 623324/1000000, Dq -> 246624/10000000, 
   Vdc -> 650, I1d -> 16043/1000, I1q -> 0};
```

At this point I can do

```
Convertertf = TransferFunctionModel[nss, s];
```

Here is a part of the numeric approximation.

```
ExpandAll[N[Convertertf, 100]][[1, 1, 1]] // N

(* Out[165]= {-6.2539325944*10^36 + 1.93055879416*10^35 s + 
  1.9678706615*10^33 s^2 + 2.11669599008*10^28 s^3 + 
  3.14177464077*10^25 s^4 + 1.53589504062*10^20 s^5 + 
  1.21221140625*10^17 s^6, -1.55842541392*10^37 + 
  6.17150836132*10^35 s + 4.47220373219*10^30 s^2 + 
  6.55274146604*10^27 s^3 + 3.95988310348*10^22 s^4 + 
  3.80827444847*10^19 s^5, -9.64607534149*10^32 - 
  3.74550092088*10^32 s - 3.02482605383*10^30 s^2 - 
  2.42295265152*10^25 s^3 - 2.0098546875*10^22 s^4 - 
  6.0159375*10^16 s^5, 
 2.39971808234*10^34 - 9.50624299627*10^32 s - 
  9.29312987358*10^27 s^2 - 1.89132246052*10^25 s^3 - 
  3.77992501089*10^19 s^4, 
 4.28257698623*10^35 + 3.14637598178*10^33 s + 
  3.55325872599*10^28 s^2 + 5.02229243353*10^25 s^3 + 
  2.52853001177*10^20 s^4 + 1.93743708356*10^17 s^5} *)
```

Notice the coefficients vary in range by around 19 orders of magnitude. A computation at machine precision is not likely to handle such a scale difference very well.

Comment: I understand the range of values is quite large but if I try and solve using the state space to transfer function equation from state space theory I am given answers that correspond to Matlab. I've added this code to the above question. I really appreciate the input.